# PHP development framework and ide (like asp.net)

Tags: php, asp.net

We have to develop an specific webpage with php and up until now we have used asp.net, the problem is that we arent able to take the tipical development steps in php.

For asp.net:

1. Design interface (aspx/html) (With visual designer)
2. Create controls events (Button click, combo select etc...) (for ex. double click on x control creates the asociated click event in codebehind)
3. Add control/bussines logic (X button clicked-> make x control visible/enabled/change its text. Intellisense or autocompletion or so, detecting the objetcs and controls that exist in the design page)

In php there doesnt seem to be clear relation between a designed page and php code (its like striping all the intellisense in asp.net and using only response.write() to do the visual changes :S)

After some searching the model we use is WebForms asp.net (not mvc .net) so the desired option would be a framework + designer as alike as WebForms as posible...

So...is there any framework + ide that helps with this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with using response.write()?  :)  I've developed large and highly interactive web portals in C#.NET using IHTTPHandler and response.write().  I guess it's a different state of mind..

Comment: What we look for is the simple development model you normally take for developing an asp.net web page or a windows forms or java or others... all the php frameworks sugested + others found work like this: Thousand commands to set up enviroment, thousand commands to create the templates, php files, etc...and it seems the visual designer + asociated codebehind (control actions) + relation between the controls in the design page and access to its properties in the code file seems a mistery to them all... ¬¬

Comment: And the viewstate functionality is handled manually too.. :/ Any framework that handles it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we used the [VS.PHP plugin](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php)...it isnt free but at least we continue using the familiar Visual Studio IDE without reconfiguring much our development setup

Answer (score 7):

I haven't used it yet, but the [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) provides support for [PHP](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) along with the Zend and Symfony frameworks, both of which are designed to support building web applications with the MVC pattern. NetBeans also has support for other aspects of web development - HTML, CSS, JavaScript. The only thing lacking right now is support for HTML5, but I believe that's on the roadmap.

I've edited some existing PHP with NetBeans, and it seems pretty sharp with code completion and suggestion, so I would suspect that support for these frameworks is also pretty solid.

Comment: +1 there are numerous frameworks that will give you an MVC structure and I myself use netbeans for PHP.  Look into the following frameworks:  CakePHP, Zend, CodeIgnitor, Symfony

Comment: @jostster You mean CodeIgniter.

Comment: @jostster: Yes, those frameworks are pretty good (I've used Cake and looked at CI before). However, I'm not sure how well integrated they are into NetBeans. Perhaps you can provide an answer addressing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prado Framework, this is like .Net, but on PHP, of course is not complete like .Net. Just search Prado Framework on Google and go to whatever link of the result page.

Sorry for my english, i just wanna help.

Bye.